# Trying to reproduce a "teleprinter effect" but the time between char remains unchanged

Tags: loops, assembly, arm, printf, cpu-registers

I am trying to produce a program that makes the "teleprinter effect", to print a string passed by argument in r0, char by char, with some time between the previous and the next print.
The program works, but there's something weird that happens. There's the r2 register that contains the "time-loser" value. In theory, the highest is the value, and the more cycles the "lose_time" subroutine has to do, so the more is the time between each char print. But actually, even if I change the r2 value to a very high one, it doesn't change nothing. Why?

**tele.s:**

```
.global tele
.type tele%function

@ r0 = array
@ r1 = signle char
@ r2 = time-loser

tele:
        mov r2,#700    // if I edit this, it doesn't change anything
        push {ip,lr}    // save lr
loop:
        ldr r1,[r0],#1    // at each loop it increase the array pointer and so r1 takes the next value in the array
        cmp r1,#0    // if the value is NULL
        beq end    // array is ended and returns
        push {r0,r2}    // save the r0(array address) and r2(my time-loser value)
        ldr r0,=message
        bl printf    // prints one single char
        bl lose_time    // then lose time
        pop {r0,r2}    // and take r0, r2 values back
        b loop    // do the cycle again
lose_time:
        sub r2,r2,#1    // sub 1
        cmp r2,#0    // until it reaches 0
        bxeq lr    // if reaches 0, it returns to "loop" subroutine
        b lose_time    // else do the cycle again
end:
        pop {ip,lr}    // if the program ends, it takes the lr back
        bx lr    // and returns

message:
        .asciz "%c\n"
```

The weird thing is that, even if I put 700 (very low value), the print is delayed anyway. It's really slow to print, like if I have put a very higher number. So why?

**main.c:**

```
int tele(char *);

int main(){
        char string[] = "Teleprinter effect";
        tele(string);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ldr r1,[r0],#1` <-- Why are you using `ldr` here? Shouldn't that be `ldrb` since you're dealing with chars?

Comment: @Michael you are right. Btw I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

I saved r2 to memory, but only restored it after calling the delay loop.

```
// r2 is 700
bl printf    // prints one single char
// r2 is garbage
bl lose_time    // then lose time
// r2 is 0
pop {r0,r2}    // and take r0, r2 values back
// r2 is 700 again
```

A guy helped me here: https://www.reddit.com/r/asm/comments/ir715b/arm_trying_to_reproduce_a_teleprinter_effect_but/